# Nuget not installing in Azure DevOps build

Tags: build, msbuild, azure-devops, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to stop archiving into code source repository anything that comes from a Nuget package. For most, since they only have dlls, it works.
My problem is that I have one Nuget with a `Content` folder in the nupkg. When building using VS2017, everything gets installed correctly but when doing the same thing using the build server (Azure DevOps Pipeline), I get

```
Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "....." because it was not found.
```

The pipeline agent version is v.2.122.1 according to Capabilities.
NuGet Task logs version 0.2.31 using NuGet 3.3.0.212 with MsBuild 14.0.

I see the nupkg files in the `packages` folder but the `Content` folder items don't get copied.

Is there anything special I need to add to my csproj or any additional steps I should add to my build definition?

Comment: Please, read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/package/nuget?view=azure-devops). Do you use the deprecated Restore NuGet Packages checkbox in the Visual Studio build step?

Comment: "Unfortunately", I don't use it. It is like the nuget restore task only restore the nupkg but does not install it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anything special I need to add to my csproj or any additional steps I should add to my build definition?

You need change your csproj file to link the files from content package instead of add the files into the project. Since you are trying to stop archiving into code source repository anything that comes from a Nuget package, then add a [nuget restore](http://NuGet%20task) task to your build definition.

As test, I create a content package and add a copy event to copy file from the content package:

[image]

After installing that package, following content will be add to the project file `.csproj` and `packages.config`:

**.csproj:**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="resources\Test.txt" />
    <Content Include="resources\Test2.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**Packages.config:**

```
<packages>
  <package id="TestContentPackage" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

**Then** we change the `.csproj` file to link the files from content package:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\Packages\TestContentPackage.1.0.0\content\resources\Test.txt" />
    <Content Include="..\Packages\TestContentPackage.1.0.0\content\resources\Test2.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

After change, the files from content package are not added to the project, just link to the project:

[image]

To verify the copy command, I add following copy command in the build event:

```
if not exist $(ProjectDir)TestFolder  mkdir $(ProjectDir)TestFolder
xcopy /y "$(SolutionDir)Packages\TestContentPackage.1.0.0\content\resources\Test2.txt" "$(ProjectDir)TestFolder"
```

All the things work fine on my local.

Then I build this project with Azure devops, you need add the nuget restore task, otherwise, Visual Studio/MSBuild could not find the files from the packages. And it also work fine.

Note: If you want to copy the files from the content folder, you need copy it from the `packages` folder.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Though this would surely work, it misses the point of NuGet which are supposed to deploy the right stuff at the right place automatically. Doing it this way could mean having to do this each time a NuGet is updated or a NuGet is added/removed) and by such is unusable. Since you work on the NuGet team, could you help me understand why VS correctly restore and install/deploy NuGets but not Azure Pipeline Task?

Comment: @bkqc, Sorry for the late reply. The difference is because you are trying to stop archiving into code source repository. Since Nuget with a Content folder in the nupkg will add file into the project, which will added to the source control. It is not what you want. So, I give you this workaround. If you want have the same behavior for VS and Azure devops, you have to add the content files to the source control.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, it seems to be the only option and as such, I will mark it as being the answer. On the other hand, it dows not make sense that the Nuget content is not used. I get it that files in the repository should have priority over the Nuget but it doesn't prevent Pipeline from doing a complete job. Where could I file a feature request?